# How to delete one of these 2 entries in openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

How to delete one of these 2 enteries. I want delete the first one.
I tryied it but always I have error

```
ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config olcOverlay={2}auditlog |grep -v "#"
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0

dn: olcOverlay={2}auditlog,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAuditlogConfig
olcOverlay: {2}auditlog
olcAuditlogFile: /var/log/ldapaudit.log

dn: olcOverlay={3}auditlog,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAuditlogConfig
olcOverlay: {3}auditlog
olcAuditlogFile: /var/log/ldap.log

search: 2
result: 0 Success
```

Comment: Can you show us the command you've run to try to delete it?

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of OpenLDAP (2.4 or older, I believe) do not support hot removal of overlays – they can only be *added* via LDAP, but removing them needs to be done offline (i.e. with the slapd service **stopped**).

The official method is to dump the cn=config database `slapcat -n 0` into an LDIF file, edit it as needed, then delete the whole slapd.d directory and rebuild it from LDIF using `slapadd -n 0`.

The unofficial method is to `rm` just the corresponding files from within `slapd.d/cn=config/`.

Comment: To be more clear: Until OpenLDAP 2.4 delete operations are not supported by back-config at all. This does affect any entry added to cn=config, not only overlays.

Comment: For me this meant; doing the slapcat -n 0, stopping the service, moving the slapd.d folder to a new folder. Then running `slapadd -l my_ldif_file.ldif -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -n 0`